# I tried to makee a prefab play a sound in Unity, but it wont play whatsoever

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio

I also have a bunch of other Objects in the scene (that aren't instantiated prefabs) which can play sound perfectly like this:

```cs
shoot.Play();
```

where `shoot` is a public AudioSource, in which i atributed in the Inspector by dragging and dropping an Audiosource of the sound effect, which i made by dragging and dropping a `.wav` file into the hierarchy.

I couldn't do the same for the prefab, obviously, so i made the AudioSource its child like this:

[The AudioSource, as the Prefabs child (imgur image link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ce5yP.png)

I then dragged and dropped in the Inspector, as the value of the public AudioSource. I tried to play the sound the same way using `hitHurt.Play();`, But it didnt work.

Someone told me to do it like this:

```cs
GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
```

Still won't work
¯\_(ツ)_/¯

edit: nvm fixed lolz

Comment: Is it in range of the AudioListener, it's on the Camera.

Comment: You have instantiated the prefab right?

Comment: @BugFinder I did, it shows up just fine, the only thing thats broken is the sound

Comment: Ok. Just checking as you didn’t mention that and it would explain why no sound

Comment: nvm, i fixed it